# Does the silencer have any cons?

Tags: call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

Does the silencer have any cons?

When you change attachments on primary the screen tells you what negatives and benefits you get. With the silencer attachment for pistols, the stats don't change and it doesn't tell you if there's any reason to get it.

Am I better off just using the silencer on all pistols? Or is there a hidden downside I don't know about yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there's no downside to it, it's rumored that the gun has slightly less range when equipped with a silencer but that has not been confirmed.